# Cannot retrieve parameters from YAML file (even if the file is found)

Tags: ros, ros2, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I wrote a very simple program in python to read parameters from a YAML file.
The YAML file is the following:

```
mqtt_node:
  ros__parameters:
    variable: 9494.98
```

and the minimal code of the node is this one:

```
class mqtt_class(Node):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__('mqtt_class')

        print()
        print(self.get_parameter('variable')._value)   # <- here is the problem
        print()
)


def main(args = None):

    rclpy.init(args = args)

    my_publisher = mqtt_class()

    rclpy.spin(my_publisher)


    my_publisher.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

This is the error I get:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/kkk/workspace/install/xxx/lib/xxx/xxx", line 11, in <module>
   load_entry_point('xxx', 'console_scripts', 'xxx')()
 File "/home/kkk/workspace/build/xxx/xxx/xxx.py", line 108, in main
  my_publisher = mqtt_class()
  File "/home/kkk/workspace/build/xxx/xxx/xxx.py", line 54, in __init__
    print(self.get_parameter('variable')._value)
   File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/node.py", line 512, in get_parameter
    raise ParameterNotDeclaredException(name)
 rclpy.exceptions.ParameterNotDeclaredException: ('Invalid access to undeclared parameter(s)', 'variable')
[ERROR] [zzzz-2]: process has died [pid 19805, exit code 1, cmd '/home/kkk/workspace/install/xxx/lib/xxx/xxx --ros-args -r __xxx:=xxx --params-file /home/kkk/workspace/install/xxx/share/xxx/params.yaml'].
```

What is wrong with the code?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382516/cannot-retrieve-parameters-from-yaml-file-(even-if-the-file-is-found)/) by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 893 on 2021-07-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error message states

```
"Invalid access to undeclared parameter(s)"
```

I don't see any  `self.declare_parameter(...)` call in your code. I guess you missed that one ([see also the docs](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Using-Parameters-In-A-Class-Python.html)).

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2021-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2021-07-15**:
Have you ever tried to run *that* tutorial? It doesn't work... the tutorial itself is buggy

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2021-07-15**:
I meant... it doesn't even compile

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2021-07-16**:
I have. And everything works.

I can also reproduce your error by commenting the `declare_parameter` call.

I'd doublecheck that you actually have the call in your code.
Also, if you could provide the error message of the "doesn't even compile" step, we could probably help with that.